# how to convert listview to gridview

Tags: android, android-listview

below is my code which works fine for showing listview horizontally. how can I change it to gridvew. What changes should I make to change it to gridview? help me please

```
public class fifthscreen extends Activity {

int IOConnect = 0;

String _response;
String status;

HorizontalListView listview;
CategoryListAdapter3 cla;

String URL, URL2;
String SelectMenuAPI;
static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();
public static String allergen2;

String name;

String url1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fifthscreen);

    listview = (HorizontalListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview2);

    cla = new CategoryListAdapter3(fifthscreen.this);
    new TheTask().execute();
}

public class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        try {


            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            _response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return _response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {

            JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(result);

            status = json2.getString("status");
            if (status.equals("1")) {

                JSONArray school4 = json2.getJSONArray("dish_allergen");
                //
                for (int i = 0; i < school4.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = school4.getJSONObject(i);

                    Category_ID.add((long) i);
                    Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));
                    Category_image.add(object.getString("image"));

                }

            }

            else {

                JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = school2.getJSONObject(i);

                    Category_ID.add((long) i);
                    Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listview.setAdapter(cla);
    }
}
     }







   public class CategoryListAdapter3 extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;

private AQuery androidAQuery;


public CategoryListAdapter3(Activity act) {
    this.activity = act;
//  imageLoader = new ImageLoader(act);
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return fifthscreen.Category_ID.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    androidAQuery = new AQuery(getcontext());
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewitem2, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title2);
    holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image2);

    holder.txtText.setText(fifthscreen.Category_name.get(position));
    //  imageLoader.DisplayImage(fifthscreen.Category_image.get(position),   
          activity, holder.imgThumb);


     androidAQuery.id(holder.imgThumb).image(fifthscreen.Category_image.get(position), false, 
     false);

    return convertView;
}
private Activity getcontext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtText;
    ImageView imgThumb;
}

          }



             <!---  fifithscreen.xml--->

                  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/test_button_text5"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

   <com.example.examplecode.HorizontalListView
           android:id="@+id/listview2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="120dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/test_button_text5"

           android:background="#ffffff"/>


      </LinearLayout>




   <!--viewitem2.xml--->



     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   >

  <ImageView
android:id="@+id/image2"
   android:layout_width="90dp"
 android:layout_height="70dp"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
 android:padding="5dp"

  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title2"
android:layout_width="90dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000"
android:paddingTop="10dp"


android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>



   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No change at all. Just set adapter of GridView as your are setting for ListView.

Comment: idid change only listview to gridview but is not work

Comment: In both files i.e. xml and your activity?

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest that you use **RecyclerView** intead.

*You might want to refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) and learn more about it.
I'm sharing my piece of code in which I'm changing my gridview to listview using RecyclerView*

If you're using Android Studio then you *might* need to add dependencies in gradle build. In my case I added as follows:

```
dependencies {
    .
    .
    .
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

---

First I'm defining a grid cell which is to be used in grid layout

**recycler_cell.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#FF000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alig=nParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Now I'm defining a list row which is to be used in list layout

**recycler_row.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#FF000000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#FF333333"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**recycler_view_test.xml**
And of course define a layout which would contain RecyclerView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Layout"
    android:id="@+id/btnChange"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

I'm sharing my piece of code but I'd strongly recommend that you go through the documentation and tutorials to understand RecyclerView to its full extent.

```
public class RecyclerViewTest extends AppCompatActivity
{
    final int GRID = 0;
    final int LIST = 1;
    int type;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager gridLayoutManager, linearLayoutManager;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    Button btnChange;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view_test);

        // Display contents in views
        final List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Person("Ariq Row 1"));
        list.add(new Person("Ariq Row 2"));
        list.add(new Person("Ariq Row 3"));

        // Finding views by id
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        btnChange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChange);

        // Defining Linear Layout Manager
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        // Defining Linear Layout Manager (here, 3 column span count)
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3);

        //Setting gird view as default view
        type = GRID;
        adapter = new MyAdapter(list, GRID);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Setting click listener
        btnChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if (type == LIST)
                {
                    // Change to grid view
                    adapter = new MyAdapter(list, GRID);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    type = GRID;
                }

                else
                {
                    // Change to list view
                    adapter = new MyAdapter(list, LIST);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    type = LIST;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}

//Defining Adapter
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    List<Person> list;
    int type;
    final int GRID = 0;
    final int LIST = 1;

    MyAdapter(List<Person> list, int type)
    {
        this.list = list;
        this.type = type;
    }

    // Inflating views if the existing layout items are not being recycled
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView;

        if (viewType == GRID)
        {
            // Inflate the grid cell as a view item
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_cell, parent, false);
        }

        else
        {
            // Inflate the list row as a view item
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row, parent, false);
        }

        return new ViewHolder(itemView, viewType);
    }

    // Add data to your layout items
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Person person = list.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(person.name);
    }

    // Number of items
    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

    // Using the variable "type" to check which layout is to be displayed
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        if (type == GRID)
        {
            return GRID;
        }

        else
        {
            return LIST;
        }
    }

    // Defining ViewHolder inner class
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView textView;
        final int GRID = 0;
        final int LIST = 1;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, int type)
        {
            super(itemView);
            if (type == GRID)
            {
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            }

            else
            {
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Data Source Class
class Person
{
    String name;

    Person(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

---

If you end up with the issue to auto fit the number of columns in case of grid layout then you might want to check [@s-marks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30256880/6484775) in which he extended the GridLayoutManager class and added his own patch of code, and also my [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082715/6484775) if you start having weird column width.

---

In my case, using his solution I made a class as follows:

```
class GridAutofitLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager
{
    private int mColumnWidth;
    private boolean mColumnWidthChanged = true;

    public GridAutofitLayoutManager(Context context, int columnWidth)
    {
        /* Initially set spanCount to 1, will be changed automatically later. */
        super(context, 1);
        setColumnWidth(checkedColumnWidth(context, columnWidth));
    }

    public GridAutofitLayoutManager(Context context, int columnWidth, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)
    {
        /* Initially set spanCount to 1, will be changed automatically later. */
        super(context, 1, orientation, reverseLayout);
        setColumnWidth(checkedColumnWidth(context, columnWidth));
    }

    private int checkedColumnWidth(Context context, int columnWidth)
    {
        if (columnWidth <= 0)
        {
            /* Set default columnWidth value (48dp here). It is better to move this constant
            to static constant on top, but we need context to convert it to dp, so can't really
            do so. */
            columnWidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 48,
                    context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        else
        {
            columnWidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, columnWidth,
                    context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return columnWidth;
    }

    public void setColumnWidth(int newColumnWidth)
    {
        if (newColumnWidth > 0 && newColumnWidth != mColumnWidth)
        {
            mColumnWidth = newColumnWidth;
            mColumnWidthChanged = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state)
    {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        if (mColumnWidthChanged && mColumnWidth > 0 && width > 0 && height > 0)
        {
            int totalSpace;
            if (getOrientation() == VERTICAL)
            {
                totalSpace = width - getPaddingRight() - getPaddingLeft();
            }
            else
            {
                totalSpace = height - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
            }
            int spanCount = Math.max(1, totalSpace / mColumnWidth);
            setSpanCount(spanCount);
            mColumnWidthChanged = false;
        }
        super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
    }
}
```

---

Then you simply have to change:

```
gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3);
```

and use your custom grid layout object, here 100 is the width of columns in dp

```
gridLayoutManager = new GridAutofitLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 100);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

For the layout of the grid/list use a merge:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<ViewStub android:id="@+id/list" 
    android:inflatedId="@+id/showlayout"
    android:layout="@layout/list_view" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<ViewStub android:id="@+id/grid" 
    android:inflatedId="@+id/showlayout"
    android:layout="@layout/grid_view" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>


</merge>
```

then define the layout for the list and the grid (and also for their items), and manage the passage between them inflating the layouts, and then use a method like this to change the current view:

```
private void changeView() {

    //if the current view is the listview, passes to gridview
    if(list_visibile) {
        listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        gridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        list_visibile = false;
        setAdapters();
    }

    else {
        gridview.setVisibility(View.GONE);                      
        listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        list_visibile = true;
        setAdapters();
    }
}
```

If you need the complete code, it is available in this article:

http://pillsfromtheweb.blogspot.it/2014/12/android-passare-da-listview-gridview.html

Answer (score 1):

Just take a `GridView` object instead of `Listview` like :

```
GridView gridView;
gridView= (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
```

And in you `getView` method of `CategoryListAdapter3` do like :

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_grid_item_leyout, null);
```

And at last in `onPostExecute` of `TheTask` do like :

```
gridView.setAdapter(cla);
```

That's It.

Answer (score 1):

Use GridView instead of below:

Then replace

```
listview = (HorizontalListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview2);
```

to

```
GridView gridview;
gridview=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
```

Everything else are fine, just set Adapter using GridView object. And you are done.

Comment: how set adapter?? suppose if i change like only this line
listview =(GridView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);  then is work fine???

Comment: Ya everything is fine, just make changes and try, and ya it will work. And please accept and upvote the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: make your gridview's height match_parent or fill_parent and in your item.xml change your LinearLayout Height and Width match_parent or fill_parent.

Comment: Ya make proper changes in your item.xml and your main.xml, nothing big now, just change the layout whatever you want.

Comment: i did if i remove scrollview then is fine  other wise gridview not show fully how to show gridview inside scroolview?

Comment: Gridview and scrollview both will not work at the same time. You cant put scrollable objects in ScrollView, becuase ScrollView already scrolls. So You can not put any scrollable objects in ScrollView.

Comment: no any idea? because in my design i make layout scroll able and also show gridview inside scrollvew

Comment: But gridview itself is a scrollable you dont need to take scrollview to scroll it. Please accept my answer if you found useful.