# Got ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when scrolling RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am using `RecyclerView` (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2) with `GridLayoutManager` and applying [dynamic column count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27000759/1197317). When the view is scrolled an exception is thrown. It seems the error happens when the `RecyclerView` about to display items that were not displayed previously (reusing or rebinding). However, if I don't use such dynamic span/column count or simply comment the line calling `GridLayoutManager.setSpanCount`, it does not happen.

I've tried to inspect the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.java), it seems the problem is related to a temporary array `mSet`.

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:361)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1097)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:957)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:985)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:1686)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
            at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
            at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How to solve this so that I can have a grid with dynamic span count? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for this issue is to adjust the mSet size. Did it by extending GridLayoutManager.

```
package android.support.v7.widget;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;

public class MyGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {
    public MyGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
        super(context, spanCount);
    }

    public MyGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, spanCount, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSpanCount(int spanCount) {
        super.setSpanCount(spanCount);
        if (mSet != null && mSet.length != spanCount) {
            View[] newSet = new View[spanCount];
            System.arraycopy(mSet, 0, newSet, 0, Math.min(mSet.length, spanCount));
            mSet = newSet;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It has been so long, but this solution is worth to try in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn´t work because mSet is package local and can´t be accessed from outside the package

Comment: @MarianKlühspies, there is no problem with putting the child class in the package `android.support.v7.widget`. Try it out! It works ;)

Comment: Do you actually know, why this happens? In my case it is because of native ads, but only sometimes, if the internet connection is very bad