# Dynamically set the columnwidth in gridlayoutmanager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am trying to do this using recycler view with gridlayoutmanager. GridLayoutmanager takes spancount. Here I want to update the view based on the width of the text in the recycler view items.

[image]

Comment: Namaste ! :-) I believe you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666143/recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-how-to-auto-detect-span-count

Comment: Also see this StaggeredGridLayoutManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Has this been solved in a native way without any libraries ?

Answer (score 5):

It's a late answer but I wanted to achieve exactly the same stuff!
Then after several hours of research, I found this lib (I don't know why I didn't find it earlier...) by Google: [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) who has a `FlexboxLayoutManager`!

How to use:

```
val layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(context)
layoutManager.flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
myRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

That's all!