# How to remove indents from RecyclerView, which arise when I download images from the Internet?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to make a gallery of images. I make it with the help of `RecyclerView`. Project downloads images form the Internet, adds it to `ImageView` and than adds it to `RecyclerView`. But there are very big indents between items in `RecyclerView` and I don't know why does it happen. I thought that it's because of the Image dimension, but than added `scaleType` and nothing happened. Also I tried to add padding/margin = 0, but it also didn't help. Here's the ImageView where the image is placed:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:padding="4dp"/>
```

It's an example of the image: https://image.ibb.co/jmHhB8/alicia_vikander_large.jpg

And here's a `RecyclerView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/previewImages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager" />
```

This is the screen of my problem:

[image]

Here's a `RecyclerView` adapter class:

```
package asus.example.com.exercise3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Actor> actors;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final Context context;

    RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Actor> actors, Context context){
        this.context = context;
        this.actors = actors;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.preview_image_layout, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Actor actor = actors.get(i);
        Glide.with(context).load(actor.getSmallImage()).into(viewHolder.avatar);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return actors.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public final ImageView avatar;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            avatar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        }
    }

}
```

What's the matter?

**UPD**

I added such class:

```
package asus.example.com.exercise3;

import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

    public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
        private int space;

        SpacesItemDecoration(int space){
            this.space = space;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRec, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state){
            outRec.left = space;
            outRec.right = space;
            outRec.bottom = space;
            if (parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) == 0){
                outRec.top = space;
            }
            else {
                outRec.top = space;
            }
        }
    }
```

But it also didn't help

Comment: set gridmanager span count https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666143/recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-how-to-auto-detect-span-count

Comment: You set your ImageView dimens to `100dp` and `centerCrop` does not do what you think it does. Are you trying to make it 2 columns and have the images stretch max width to fit the columns?

Comment: @TWL,there are should be 2 columns,but there's not only one line. If you will the activity you will see another photos, but another lines are not seen on the screen because of the indents

Comment: @rajahsekar there's no problem with columns,there are big indents between the lines. How can I remove them?

Comment: This is how you do grid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the Also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531996/android-recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-column-spacing so I feel it's a duplicate.

Comment: @CmosBattery, updated the question