# Android FlexboxLayoutManager last row alignment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout

I am trying to use FlexboxLayoutManager to layout square shape items. However the last row has only two items so that they centre align. That makes things look super bad. My code is below. Is there a way to fix this?

```
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(activity);
layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.SPACE_BETWEEN);
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing `setJustifyContent` . It should work that's the default arrangement of FlexBox.

Comment: thanks but that's FLEX_START. Which leaves a large empty space at the right end of the view.  I want to evenly space items yet the last row aligned as same as the rows above. any workarounds ?

Comment: The image u have attached  is Grid Alignment . Why r u using `FlexBox` ? u can use `GridLayoutManager` for it .

Comment: thats what  I used, but how do I set the number of columns? FlexBox computes the columns dynamically, right?

Comment: You could set the span count (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager#setSpanCount(int)) dynamically based on the screen width by doing the calculation. Here you can find a solution to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666143/recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-how-to-auto-detect-span-count .

Comment: Can not think of Solution with Flex Box . One hack is you can add dummy items to make it a full row and use a transparent View ad dummy item .

Comment: @Patola Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is dirty, but works. Place the `FlexLayout` inside a `FramLayout`, Just don't forget to set the layout parameters to *WRAP_CONTENT* with *center* gravity over horizontal axis.

```
flexbox=new FlexboxLayout(context);
flexbox.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
flexbox.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
flexbox.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START);

FrameLayout container=new FrameLayout(context);
LayoutParams lp=new LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.gravity= Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
container.addView(flexbox,lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to approach this is setting `justifyContent` to `SPACE_BETWEEN`. This will fit as many items in one line, leaving empty spaces of equal width between (thus centering items). The "stranglers" on the last line will be left aligned.

**Kotlin**

```
val layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(context).apply {
    justifyContent = JustifyContent.SPACE_BETWEEN
}
```

**Java**

```
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.SPACE_BETWEEN);
```

You might have to adjust your left and right padding of the recyclerView as the most-left and most-right spaces won't be calculated (the first and last view will touch the borders of parent)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by setting two things:

1. In code:

```
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START);
```

2. In layout changed hierarchy to this:

```
- ConstraintLayout
-- RecyclerView (width is "wrap_content", edges constrained to sides)
```

So the list itself is centered, but the list items are aligned to lists left side.