# how to change from listview to gridview

Tags: android, gridview

i am new to android app development, so far i learnt to create splash screen and moving from one activity to another activity when a button pressed. now i plan to develop a app for image gallery from urls. from this [site][1]

[1]: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e14021/universal-image-loader-in-android/ i got some ideas, i have started my codings, but i want gridview instead of list view. i have created a separate xml's for gridview, but i dont know how to implement gridview in java. someone please help me to solve this?

Comment: Please refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243216/how-to-convert-listview-to-gridview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45456602/5973946

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert listview to gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243216/how-to-convert-listview-to-gridview)